# ssh tunnel to another ssh tunnel?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet

In my country (let's say for example Iran), we do not have access to the internet. We can just reach some internal websites and even we do not have access to Google. In this scenario, I have a VPS in my country(let's say VPS1) that has access to the Internet and I can ssh-tunnel to it and reach google, But that's just some filtered restricted Internet.

command: `ssh user@vps1 -D 7000 -N`

so when I want to connect to unfiltered internet, I have to connect to that VPS1 via ssh, then, I make an ssh-tunnel from VPS1 to VPS2(which is in another country), and then I can have unfiltered internet in VPS1.

command: `ssh -i <key> anotheruser@vps2 -D 7001 -N`

my question is, is there any other way that I can connect my local machine to unfiltered Internet via this 2 VPSs?

Comment: I understand you can't connect directly from your machine to VPS2, right? And the problem is, when you make that second ssh tunnel from VPS1 to VPS2, you have unfiltered Internet on your VPS1, but have no way to pass it on to your machine, right? In that case, can you VPN into VPS1 instead of creating that first ssh tunnel? You will be directly connected to VPS1 via VPN tunnel, and if you properly configure routing on your VPS1, you will be able to reach everything that VPS1 will be able to reach.

Comment: @raj hey raj, yes I can not connect directly to VPS2 from my machine, and yes I don't know a way to pass the Internet to my machine from VPS1 connected to VPS2. also, I didn't know about VPN tunnels. I'll try it but if you could provide any document that would be great. thanks a lot

Comment: I am sorry but I never set up a VPN server myself, so I have no document that I can recommend to you. Maybe someone else will recommend something. You need to set up a VPN server on your VPS1, then probably you can use VPN client built into Ubuntu to connect to it.